# Timer working improperly

Tags: c++, timer, sdl

I have a problem with a timer class based on a SDL timer.

```
class CTimer
{
    public:
    CTimer(): startTick(0), endTick(0), curTime(0), running(false) {};
    void Start() { startTick += SDL_GetTicks() - endTick; running = true; };
    void Stop() { endTick = SDL_GetTicks(); running = false; };
    void Reset() { startTick = 0; endTick = 0; curTime = 0; };
    inline int operator()() { return running ? curTime = ((int) SDL_GetTicks - startTick) / 1000 + 1 : curTime; };
    private:
    int startTick;
    int endTick;
    int curTime;
    bool running;
};
```

The () operator should return time in seconds (stored in curTime). But it always returns 4202 (curTime is always equal to that). What am I doing wrong?

Test code:

```
int main()
{
    SDL_Init (SDL_INIT_TIMER);
    CApp::CTimer timer;
    timer.Start();
    for (int i = 0; i < 15; ++i)
    {
        SDL_Delay (1000);
        std::cout << timer() << '\n';
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a perfect example of why you don't want to use old-style C casts in C++.

```
(int) SDL_GetTicks
```

The missing parentheses on the function call mean you're casting a pointer to the function to an int, not the return value. Surprisingly enough the pointer to the function never changes.

Comment: I see.  So the compiler warning was seen and cast away :-(

Comment: My mingw didn't show any warning. I will not use any c-cast in my future code. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Are you missing parentheses for SDL_GetTicks?

```
inline int operator()() { return running ? curTime = ((int) SDL_GetTicks - startTick) / 1000 + 1 : curTime; };
```

Answer (score 1):

For starters,

```
inline int operator()() { return running ? curTime = 
    ((int) SDL_GetTicks - startTick) / 1000 + 1 : curTime; };
```

should be

```
inline int operator()() { return running ? curTime = 
    ((int) SDL_GetTicks() - startTick) / 1000 + 1 : curTime; };
```

I would think.

Did you get a warning error about this?

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the attempted call to `SDL_GetTicks` instead of `SDL_GetTicks()` causing it to take the address of that function (and always returning the constant as you observed), it looks like if you call `Start` and then `Stop` before calling `operator()` you won't get a meaningful result.